# call to window.open() returns null on IE 11 + Windows 8.1 Preview

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, windows-8.1

I am doing somethig like this,where MyConfig is a aspx page.

```
   winOpen=window.open('/Account/Register','MyConfig','toolbar=no,status=no,location=no,menubar=0,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=' + wWidth + ',height='+ wHeight + ',top=' + wTop + ',left=' +wLeft);
```

winOpen.focus();

It returns null.It is working fine in chrome + WIndows 8.1 preview,But it is not working in IE 11.

EDIT

I have added one more line in the question and actually that line is failing since window.open() return null and so is winOpen.focus().I turned to compatibility mode and than launched the page now it is giving me the same WebPage error but I am able to navigate to the page.I wanted it to work in without compatibility mode setting.user might not know the setting.

Comment: Isn't the first argument supposed to be a string as well?

Comment: sorry I will update the question

Comment: You need to debug. What are the values of `wWidth`, `wHeight`, `wTop` and `wLeft`? Also, is a window being opened and just the variable is null?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Width =1036,Height=700,Top=34,Left=165

Comment: window is not coming IE 11 as it is.If i turn to compatibility mode the windows comes.

Comment: Try giving full URL, e.g. `winOpen = window.open('http://localhost/Account/Register/page.aspx', ...`

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nop Its not working.Even I directly pasted the url in IE11 its not coming up.but if i do the same thing in chrome its loading that page. I guess doPostback failing in it.

Comment: you can use <a href='...' target='_blank'> it works fine for me..

Answer (score 2):

uncheck "Enable Protected Mode" in internet options

Answer (score 0):

Your first argument is supposed to be a string, and you are missing a plus sign by `wHeight`:

```
winOpen=window.open('/Account/Register','MyConfig','toolbar=no,status=no,location=no,menubar=0,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=' + wWidth + ',height=' + wHeight + ',top=' + wTop + ',left=' +wLeft);
```

**Edit**: Check and make sure your IE allows popups on the site you are using to test. If it does not, and the popup does not open, it will return null. Allowing popups will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Same problem with IE 11 on windows 10

At difference than @Khodor workaround, I get the expected behavior doing this:

1. Open internet options popup.
2. Select security tab.
3. Check 'Enable Protected Mode'.
4. Close and Open IE again.

*I thougt that the null was caused for 'not found' response, ssl, different domain, etc. I tested and dicarded all of them.*